# R tibble: get column name of first column for referencing

Tags: r, tibble

I have a `tibble` like:

```
df <- tribble(~employee_name, ~salary, ~weight,
             "sarah", 90000, 110, 
             "john", 50000, 150, 
             "jones", 70000, 160, 
             )
```

I'd actually like to grab the values in the first column as a vector (which will always comprise of strings):

```
[1] "sarah" "john" "jones"
```

This can easily be done with `df$employee_name`, but what if the name of the first column isn't always `employee_name`? I'd like a way of grabbing the first column name, so that I can eventually retrieve the values of the first column as a column. I've tried:

```
first_col_name <- df[,1]
df$first_colname

# Error in df$first_colname : object of type closure is not subsettable
```

I assume that the error message means that the `df$colname` operation requires `colname` to be an actual column name, and cannot be a variable.

Comment: Try 
`df%>%pull(1)`
You don't need to know the first column name. Just use `dplyr::pull(1)`

Comment: `df[,1]` is not column name, it is the value.  if you have use `first_col_name <- names(df)[1]` then `df[[first_col_name]]` gives the output

Comment: `df[, colnames(df)[1]]`

Comment: All verified working, and should be left for posterity as multiple possible solutions; someone post an answer so I can accept as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
df%>%dplyr::pull(1)
```

this will get you the first column without the need to know the column name